# Exponents and powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given, $a^x = b^y = c^z$, and $a^3 = b^2c$, then find $\dfrac {3}{x} - \dfrac {2}{y}$:

**My try:**

Let $a^x = b^y = c^z = k$; guessing that $b = c = a$, somethings like that, 
but could not come to a conclusion.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Where you've left of, we have $$a=k^{\dfrac 1x},b=\cdots,c=\cdots$$

As $\displaystyle a^3=b^2c, \left(k^{\dfrac 1x}\right)^3=\left(k^{\dfrac 1y}\right)^2\cdot\left(k^{\dfrac 1z}\right)$

$\displaystyle\implies k^{\dfrac3x}=k^{\left(\dfrac2y+\dfrac1z\right)}$

Now for $p\ne0,$ $p^u=p^v\implies p^{u-v}=1$

$\implies$

(i)either $u-v=0$

(ii)or $p=1$

(iii) or $p=-1$ and $u-v$ is even.

Comment: @Apurv, what was the motivation of your editing. As the three cases need to be written separately for better clarity

Comment: the implies symbol looked odd, so for continuity, I edited ur post.. Anyways, if u don't like it, just reject the edit..

Comment: @Apurv, I'd to sacrifice a version. Anyway, I thought of changing it in another way :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $c=a^3b^{-2}=c^{3z/x}c^{-2z/y}=c^{z(\frac{3}{x}-\frac{2}{y})}$.